# arules package installation issue - Not available for R V. 3.2.2

Tags: arules

I am not able to install "arules" package on my machine. I am using windows with R version 3.2.2.

> install.packages("arules")

Warning in install.packages :
package ‘arules’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2)

Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error when i updated R to 4.1.xx. I had to uninstall R and re-install 4.0.xx It solved the error for me. I suspect you are getting this error cause the version of R you are using is a bit old. uninstall R and update it to 4.0.xx.

tutorial for updating R
https://www.r-statistics.com/2015/06/a-step-by-step-screenshots-tutorial-for-upgrading-r-on-windows/

Comment: Where did you get R 4.0.1 from ? The lastest version on cran as of today is 3.5.

Comment: I tested your suggestion. Updating from 3.2 to 3.5 worked.